# Excel formula to sequentially print all the values of a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Excel Example]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMC0j.jpg)

I want a formula to place into **cell B1** that will search column A and insert the first value it finds.

Then in **cell B2**, a formula that will insert the 2nd result and so forth.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With strings you can use this **array formula** in cell B1 and drag it down-

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$15)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROW())),"")
```

That's an array formula, so when you type it, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shft</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>enter</kbd>.

---

With a numbers only list you could use this

```
=Small(A1:A16,Row())
```

Comment: Perfect! this is great and exactly what I needed! thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just sort column A, that will flush all the blank lines out.

If this is not an option, you need a rather complex approach - Excel is not a programming language that allows to describe or execute *processes*, but simply calculates *formulas*.

Here is one possible approach:

1. Concatenate all values of column A, separated by a character that is not used anywhere, for example `|` or `;`. the blank lines will result in multiple separators next to each other: `=A2&A3&A4&A5&A6...` (keep going of course, all the way through your content of A).
2. Replace multiple separators by one: `||` ->`|`, using `REPLACE()` or such
3. split the remainder at separators (using `FIND()` or similar)

Steps 1. and 2. are best done in a helper cell somewhere, but you can force it all in one big formula of you insist.